# How can i extract underlined text from pdf file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

[Link to the underlined text image from PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUVvm.png)

Please refer to the above image snippet from PDF i am using for extraction.
I would need only texts like Python, Git and GitHub etc from it.

Please advice, how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but please let me know how i can achieve this using python ? or Is there any tool available ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.